# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar and Outlook 2007

Tags: 2010, calendar, outlook

I have a site collection that uses their SharePoint with outlook. They are starting to experience issues when it comes to the two of them syncing.

Test cases:

1. Add Event to Outlook. Event syncs to SharePoint calendar. Delete event via outlook. Event is deleted off Sharepoint. (Works Fine)
2. Add Event to Outlook. Event syncs to SharePoint calendar. Delete event via SharePoint. Outlook retains event (Fails even after Send/Receive)

So I'm focusing on test case 2. I've noticed that if I was to run test case 2 then modify the event from outlook in anyway (change title, time, add notes) outlook will start the Send/Receive then once it completes the event will delete. Like it doesn't realize the event has been deleted until it tries to save a modification to it.

Another thing that may be related to this, I get two errors that appear during the Send/Receive that clear out pretty quick so I'm guessing they are resolving themselves.

1. Task 'SharePoint' reported error(0x80004005): 'The SharePoint List(Department - Group Calendar) cannt be found. If the problem continues, contact the SharePoint site administrator.'
2. Task 'SharePoint' reported error(0x0004010F): 'The SharePoint List (Department - Group Calendar) cannot be found. If the problem continues, contact the SharePoint site administrator. An error occurred connecting to the https://*root site*. A connection to https://*root site*/sites/department, an alternate Web address for the SharePoint site, will be attempted.'

Comment: In case its not obvious, the calendar is located in the `Department` site collection. I'm not sure why in error 2 its trying to connect to the root site instead of going directly to the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue we had (last year). There is (still) a bug that exists in Outlook 2007 in the synchronization with Sharepoint. We found upgrading to Outlook 2010 fixed the issue. We had extensive testing and conversations with our Microsoft Rep. It seemed to be an issue mostly with SP Calendars (in SP2007, in our case) that had a high number of items. As Microsoft was well on their way past Outlook 2007 at the time, the bug fix, if I remember correctly, was not a high priority for Microsoft. Moving to Outlook 2010, as was planned and done about 6 months later, completely cured the issue for us. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll see if I can find any info on when we will be upgrading to Outlook 2010 hopefully I can get that rolling soon.